# how to login a user with email or username in django custom user model

Tags: python, django, backend

This is my current code can anyone please add the required code to allow a user to login with email or username

> backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend, UserModel

class CaseInsensitiveModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        
        try:
            case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)

        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

> custom user models

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your custom user model?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: I tried adding code, but he says most of my question is code, and he won't let me save the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `ModelBackend` that will focus on retrieving the `UserModel` where the `USERNAME_FIELD` matches, or the `email` field matches with the [**`__iexact`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact).

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    user_field = UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    
    try:
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(
            Q((f'{user_field}__iexact', username)) | Q(username__iexact=username)
        )
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        UserModel().set_password(password)

    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```